# Redimensionar imagem com PHP antes de enviar para o servidor de imagens

Tags: php

Estou com um pequeno probleminha. Quero limitar o tamanho da imagem a ser enviar para o servidor e também a sua resolução em pixels. por exemplo, definir um tamanho máximo de 1mb por imagem, e resolução máxima 500x500.

atualmente uso esse código para tentar fazer isso

```
if ( isset( $_FILES[ 'arquivo' ][ 'name' ] ) && $_FILES[ 'arquivo' ][ 'error' ] == 0 )
{
    $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES[ 'arquivo' ][ 'tmp_name' ];
    $nome = $_FILES[ 'arquivo' ][ 'name' ];
    // Pega a extensão
    $extensao = pathinfo ( $nome, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
    // Converte a extensão para minúsculo
    $extensao = strtolower ( $extensao );
    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    // Aqui eu enfileiro as extensões permitidas e separo por ';'
    // Isso serve apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
    if ( strstr ( '.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao ) ) {
        // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
        // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
        // Evita nomes com acentos, espaços e caracteres não alfanuméricos
        $novoNome = uniqid ( time () ) . '.' . $extensao;

        // Concatena a pasta com o nome
        $destino = '../../imagensDb/'.$novoNome;

        // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
        if ( @move_uploaded_file ( $arquivo_tmp, $destino ) ) {
            $img = $novoNome;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize `$_FILES['arquivo']['size']` para verificar o tamanho da imagem direto no código, caso na seja necessário utilizar as configurações de upload de arquivos no **php.ini**, sendo que o valor retornado é em bytes, do arquivo enviado. Para as dimensões use a função `getimagesize`, passando como parametro `$_FILES['arquivo']["tmp_name"]`

```
if (isset($_FILES['arquivo']['name']) && $_FILES['arquivo']['error'] == 0) {
    $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
    $nome = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
    // Pega a extensão
    $extensao = pathinfo($nome, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Converte a extensão para minúsculo
    $extensao = strtolower($extensao);
    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    // Aqui eu enfileiro as extensões permitidas e separo por ';'
    // Isso serve apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
    if (strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao)) {

        $msg = "";

        if ($_FILES['arquivo']['size'] > 1000000) {
            $msg = "Tamanho Máximo da imagem foi ultrapassado, sendo permitido até 1MB";
        }

        $imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['arquivo']["tmp_name"]);
        $largura = $imageinfo[0];
        $altura = $imageinfo[1];

        if ($msg = "" && ($largura < 500 && $altura < 500)) {
            $msg = "Dimensão não permitida.";
        }

        if ($msg == "") {
            // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
            // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
            // Evita nomes com acentos, espaços e caracteres não alfanuméricos
            $novoNome = uniqid(time()) . '.' . $extensao;

            // Concatena a pasta com o nome
            $destino = '../../imagensDb/' . $novoNome;

            // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
            if (@move_uploaded_file($arquivo_tmp, $destino)) {
                $img = $novoNome;
            }
        } else {
            echo $msg;
        }
    }
}
```